# mySQL help in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am running a query to populate a dropdown menu, however the column I am using a list of company names, this means that the company name is often repeated, is there way to only get each repeated value only once? So for instance if I have in the table something like,

```
Company 1
Company 1
Company 2
Company 3
Company 4
Company 4
```

But I would like the dropdown to return,

```
Company 1
Company 2
Company 3
Company 4
```

I am using the database libray and active record to write the sql like this currently I need to know what I use to only show each result once,

```
function getAllUsers() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('userProfileTable');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Or what would the raw sql be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('userProfileTable');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->db->distinct();` which adds the `DISTINCT` keyword to your query.

Modify your function to this:

```
function getAllUsers() {
    $this->db->distinct();
    $query = $this->db->get('userProfileTable');

    return $query->result_array()
}
```

which produces

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM userProfileTable
```

Please note that `select` and `from` have been removed from your original function because `get` simply does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from userProfileTable;
```

Comment: have you read this part of question: "Or what would the raw sql be?" ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
function getAllUsers() {
    $this->db->distinct();
    $query = $this->db->get('userProfileTable');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```